# template error codeblocks,c++, codeblocks, error

Tags: c++

I want to compile:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"gettype.*"
using namespace std;


int main() { 
int i;
cout << getType(i) << endl; 
unsigned int ui;
cout << getType(ui) << endl; 
char c;
cout << getType(c) << endl; 
double d;
cout << getType(d) << endl;
bool b;
cout << getType(b) << endl; 
float f;
cout << getType(f) << endl; 
}
```

With this in as template:

```
#ifndef GETTYPE_T
#define GETTYPE_T

template <typename T>
std::string getType(T t) { return "unbekannter Typ";}
template<typename T> std::string getType(int t) { return "int";}
template<typename T> std::string getType(unsigned int t) { return "unsigned                  int";}
template<typename T> std::string getType(double t) { return "double";}
template<typename T> std::string getType(char t) { return "char";}
template<typename T> std::string getType(bool t) { return "bool";}
#endif
```

I am getting this errors from the console in codeblocks:

```
||=== Build: Debug in gettype.t (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
gettype.t.c|6|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before     '<' token|
gettype.t.c|9|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token|
gettype.t.c|10|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__'        before '<' token|
gettype.t.c|11|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__'    before '<' token|
gettype.t.c|12|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token|
gettype.t.c|13|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__'  before '<' token|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

i donno what´s wrong here...:-( thx in advance for your time :-)
cheers.

Comment: `#include "gettype.*"` ???

Comment: FYI, the question title is not for tags, it's for an actual title.

Comment: #include "gettype.*" was a mistake...it does not work with the extension .t

Comment: Thank you  for your answers.                                                                                                                  I changed it to:                                                                                                    template <typename T>                                                                                        std::string getType(int t) { return "int";}
std::string getType(bool t) { return "bool";}

Comment: and in the main:                                                                                            #include"gettype.t"                                                                                            but it still does not work...:-(

Comment: What's the name of the file with the `gettype` function templates in? It should end in `.h` or you are going to confuse codeblocks, that's probably why it is trying to compile it as a C file.

Comment: now it works. :-) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to 'specialize' the templated version of the function, you just need overloads, without `template<typename T>` for the known types:

```
std::string getType(int t) { return "int";}
std::string getType(bool t) { return "bool";}
```

And so on. These will overload the templated version.

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
#include "gettype.*"
```

The error message tells you that GCC is including a file called `gettype.t.c` and trying to compile it as a C file.

I have no idea what you're trying to do, but if you fix your include so it just includes `gettype.t` not `gettype.*` it will work (why does your header have a `.t` extension anyway?)